# Issues with ExecuteAction infopath Addin

Tags: c#, infopath

I'm working on a COM AddIn for Infopath written in C#. The addin will be in a form of a button that copies the text under cursor, processes it, and should paste a formatted output.

Everything works perfect, except for the paste.
To paste the data which is stored as RTF in the clipboard I'm using

```
this.Application.ActiveWindow.XDocument.View.ExecuteAction("Paste", Type.Missing);
```

The problem with this is that it messes up the Font (everything shows up as bold). The data in the clipboard is correct.

I know this, because, oddly enough, the data is pasted correctly if I remove this line and manually press Paste/Ctrl+V.

So to sum up ExecuteAction("Paste") != manual paste. What can I use to 'simulate' the manual paste action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try simulating a manual paste through the command bars as explained here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/3c7f17ee-3c7c-4efd-9cbe-66b2f8f2c2d1

They go through `.View.Window.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar` to the specific control based on index but you might be able to make it more robust by using `FindControl()` at the command bars level.

If you are using InfoPath 2010 you might have to go through the Ribbon instead of CommandBars.